# Chrome graphics glitch

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

These are some weird graphics glitches I have on Chrome. I have Intel integrated graphics and my processor is Intel i5 8400.

[image: Stack Overflow]

[image: IMG]

Notice that the second "o" in the word "Google" has two weird green circles. And the Stack Overflow logo also looks green where it should normally be orange.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where some images had this border whatsoever, and for me the solution was turning the hardware acceleration on (in Chrome).
Hope it helps!

Comment: I installed Windows and the problem went away...